# Can't target specific LI elements using child selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

```js
$('ul.list > li:not(.sublist)').click(function() {
  alert("working now");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li class="special">Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>
    <ul class="sublist">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>2</li>
      <li>3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I'm trying to only select the LI elements that descend from the  class(.list). Invariably, the  children of the class(.sublist) are also activated when I click.Eeverything I click on gives me the alert. This is not what I want. I'm getting frustrated because I know the answer is simple but I just can't figure it out.

I've also tried using this:

```
$('ul.list li').not('.sublist').click(function(){
    alert('working');
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [direct child combinator, `>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators), in order to only select direct children elements:

```
ul.list > li
```

But since this still selects the `li` that contains the `.sublist` element, use a combination of the [`:not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)/[`:has()`](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selectors:

```
$('ul.list > li:not(:has(.sublist))').on('click', function () {
    // ...
});
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3kz9r3ob/)

```js
$('ul.list > li:not(:has(.sublist))').on('click', function () {
    alert('working');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li class="special">Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="sublist">
            <li>1</li>
            <li>2</li>
            <li>3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've done this, and the children of the .sublist are still activated.

Comment: Yes, just saw it. It worked. Amazing. Thank you so much. Is there some resource you can point me to for further study? I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I never came across a :has selector.