# Child selector not working as expected, what is wrong?

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list and I want the style to hit only on the immediate "li" elements that's why I used the ">" child selector.

But what is happening is that even the "li" elements nested inside the "ul" element which is in turn nested under the first level "li" elements are also being styled, what is wrong here?

Here's the CSS,

```
#nav > li {
    background-color: yellow;}
```

And here's my markup.

```
<div>
  <ul id="nav">
   <li>This is a list</li>
   <li>This is a list</li>
   <li>
    <ul>
     <li>This is a list</li>
     <li>This is a list</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question 2 days ago.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28012951/css-select-second-level-elements .. also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894099/cant-target-specific-li-elements-using-child-selectors .. even though you are setting the background color on the direct child, it still encompasses the children, thus it's visible.

Comment: In what way does it encompass the children?

Comment: Simply put, the direct child `li` elements are still the parents of all the children. Thus the nested `ul` will have that background color (because it's transparent and the parent's background color is visible through it).

Comment: ..therefore, you want one of the following: http://jsfiddle.net/58h8fjnh/ .. or .. http://jsfiddle.net/k4uxr566/

Comment: Think of it as setting the background on body - it encompasses everything in the page in much the same way.

Comment: But the W3 specification says that property is not inherited, what's up with that?